# Orchard 1.8 Package Installation Failure

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I am trying to install a package (oForms) with a new Orchard 1.8 installation, but receiving the following error:

"Package installation failed: There was an error installing the requested package. This can happen if the server does not have write access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site. If the site is running in shared hosted environement, adding write access to these folders sometimes needs to be done manually through the Hoster control panel. Once Themes and Modules have been installed, it is recommended to remove write access to these folders."

This seemed rather straightforward, however my host has confirmed permissions are fine (and even added Everyone/Full Control to the folder), so I'm lost and appears to be happening with all modules from the Gallery, not just oForms. I changed the `Config/log4net.config` file to log everything, and I don't see anything specific in there except where it logs the same message above. Nothing outside of that stands out at all.

Is there a way to see why this is failing? Or, if not, is there a way to get the module and install it manually? I tried to download from the gallery, but it's just a NuGet package so I'm not sure how to take that and grab the raw module files.

Comment: Side note: it is a bad idea to install modules in production. You should install on your dev machine, then deploy, instead.

Comment: Oh, whenever I do anything Orchard it's straight to production. I use it sort of like WordPress, and don't do any custom stuff with it so straight to production works well. If I ever get to extending it with code (not just views), I'd definitely go this route though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a program like 7zip to unzip the nuget package, then copy in the module manually yourself.

As for the permissions, when adding a new permission to the folder use:

> IIS AppPool\name of your application pool

Answer (score 0):

I also had this exact error message when installing modules from the gallery, and it took me a while to figure out what was happening. I made new installations, copying over files one-by-one, and eventually found the culprit. For my case anyways...

For me, it was all due to a bad formatting in my custom Theme. Specifically the Theme.txt file. The line where is says `Version:`, I had it formatted without any `"."`

Good:

```
Version: 1.0
```

BAD:

```
Version: 1
```

Yes, doing this simple mistake prevented me from installing Modules.